# Infinite loop when using jQuery to trigger event on object with function of same name

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, events

That title probably doesn't help much, I tried though.  Anyway I ran into this extremely mysterious (and frustrating) bug resulting in a `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` in some OO JS I'd written.  Took me a couple hours but I finally got to the cause.  Here's a simple example that will result in the same exception:

```
// Class
var Foo = function(){
    // "Public" function
    this.bar = function(){
        console.log('loop!');
        $(this).trigger('bar');
    }
}

var foo = new Foo();
$(foo).trigger('bar');
```

Running this code will result in `loop!` being logged to the console a ton of times before eventually resulting in the range exception.

Clearly there's something about jQuery's `trigger` function I don't understand, and it boils down to this: **why would foo's `bar` function be called at all?**  Yes, the event name and the class's function name are the same, but I don't understand how the two are related.

Comment: Sorry, but I cant see the problem. You first call `bar` from `foo`.. and inside `bar`, you call again `bar` from `foo` (this). So it is an expected behavior.

Comment: ...resulting in a loop...

Comment: Interesting...it seems that the methods of a constructor function act as events, and can be `trigger`ed using jQuery. Edit: Doesn't have to be a constructed object. Any regular object can have any of its methods triggered

Comment: @wendelbsilva So, you're saying that `$(foo).trigger('bar')` is equivalent to `foo.bar()`?  That's not true in my experience, the former *triggers an event* (not "calls a function") on the target object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would need to use `.triggerHandler` to mitigate this issue.

Per the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/):

> Note: For both plain objects and DOM objects other than window, if a
>   triggered event name matches the name of a property on the object,
>   jQuery will attempt to invoke the property as a method if no event
>   handler calls event.preventDefault(). If this behavior is not desired,
>   use `.triggerHandler()` instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/bcsqF/

Comment: Apparently I needed to (re-)RTFM.  Ugh, that spells it out quite well, thank you.  I'll look into `triggerHandler`.

Comment: No sweat! We could all use a bit of RTFM! Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

From the [jQuery Trigger documentation](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/):

> Description: Execute all handlers and behaviors attached to the
>   matched elements for the given event type.

`bar` is a propery or behavior of `Foo`, so the `bar` property (which is a method) is called `on $(foo).trigger('bar');`. In the `bar` function, the `this` refers to the `foo` class, so the  `$(this).trigger('bar');`. calls the bar function on foo. This would be qual to calling this.bar() in the bar function, which is a more obvious recursion.

All in all this isn't´the behaviour I would have expected to, I expected that Trigger could be only called on DOM elements, but the documentation states otherwise.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, it's clear to me now but as you said, not what I expected!

Answer (score 2):

Lets dig into jQuery source.

#### [trigger](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.fn.trigger):

```
function (type, data) {
    return this.each(function () {
        jQuery.event.trigger(type, data, this);
    });
}
```

#### [jQuery.event](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.Event)

```
function (src, props) {

    // Allow instantiation without the 'new' keyword
    if (! (this instanceof jQuery.Event)) {
        return new jQuery.Event(src, props);
    }

    ...

    // Put explicitly provided properties onto the event object
    if (props) {
        jQuery.extend(this, props);
    }

    ...
}
```

As you can see `jQuery.event` object is constructed in a way that it's extended with own properties of you object. It means that you can use `trigger` to invoke them. Hence a loop.

Comment: Appreciate that, thank you.  I am working with a minified version of jQuery, but had I not soon figured it out I was going to do exactly what you suggested - dig in!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to calling any attached event handlers, `trigger` will also attempt to invoke the native behavior. So if you are calling `$('form').trigger('submit')` in addition to executing any bound handlers, it will fire the native method `form.submit` to actually send the form. I suppose trigger looks on the object for a method with the same name as the triggered event, and assumes that to be accompanying native event, which it then calls.

Comment: Yep, definitely makes sense to me now.  Thanks for your answer.